# how to caculate the step response of the second order system with nonzero initial condition, $y¨ + 2ξω_ny˙ +2y = 0, y(0) = 0, y˙(0) = c$

Tags: laplace-transform, homogeneous-equation

How to caculate the step response of the second order system with nonzero initial condition,$$ \ddot{y}+ 2ξω_n\dot y +2y = 0, y(0) = 0, \dot y(0) = c$$ (where $c$ is a contant)

Question: how to calculate the transfer function of this equation? since the input function is $0$? so  no way to calculate the step response of this equation.

Answer (score 0):

We have a linear differential equation with constant coefficients:

$$L[y]=y''(t) + 2 \xi  \omega _n y'(t)+2 y(t)$$

In order to solve $L[y]=0$ we try using $y(t)=\exp (\lambda \cdot t)$ and get the characteristic polynomial

$$p_{L}(\lambda)=\lambda ^2+2 \xi \omega_{n} \cdot \lambda  _n+2$$

Then the transfer function is

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{p_{L}(s)}=\frac{1}{s^2+2 \xi \omega_{n} \cdot s+2}$$

For the step response we use the Heaviside $\theta(t)$ unit step function and it's Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_t[\theta (t)](s)=\frac{1}{s}$$

The step response using inverse Laplace transform then is

$$\sigma(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[H(s)\cdot\frac{1}{s}\right](t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s \left(s^2+2 \xi \omega _n  \cdot s +2\right)}\right](t)$$

The general solution is:

$$\sigma(t)=\frac{\xi  \omega _n e^{t \left(-\sqrt{\xi ^2 \omega _n^2-2}-\xi  \omega _n\right)}}{4 \sqrt{\xi ^2 \omega _n^2-2}}-\frac{\xi  \omega _n e^{t \left(\sqrt{\xi ^2 \omega _n^2-2}-\xi  \omega _n\right)}}{4 \sqrt{\xi ^2 \omega _n^2-2}}-\frac{1}{4} e^{t \left(-\sqrt{\xi ^2 \omega _n^2-2}-\xi  \omega _n\right)}-\frac{1}{4} e^{t \left(\sqrt{\xi ^2 \omega _n^2-2}-\xi  \omega _n\right)}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Example with $\xi=1$ and $\omega_{n}=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\sigma(t)=-\frac{e^{-\frac{t}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{7} t}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{7} t}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}$$

Visualize example:

[image: MSE_Q4689498]

See also [Transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function)

Comment: could you please explain why we could get H(s) using  characteristic  polynomial, as we know that the H(s) is the ration of lapalce transform of output and  lapalce transform of input.

Comment: In fact a transfer function only makes sense with an input like this:

$$y''(t) + 2 \xi  \omega _n y'(t)+2 y(t)=x(t)$$

Then $Y(s)=H(s)\cdot X(s)$

Comment: could you pleae explain more from pL(λ)=λ2+2ξωn⋅λn+2 to get H(s), any priciplels? or any caculation?

Comment: Read this: [Transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function)